# How to have a static IP to be listed as a user on a secured FTP?

Tags: ftp, static-ip

I have to be given access to an FTP server which has rigid security policy. To be able to access it I have to send them my IP.

However, I do not have a static IP. My host has a lot of IP addresses so they cannot even whitelist me as `12.34.*.*` because the ISP has IP range that does not start with `12.*.*.*` only. And they cannot give me the list of all their IP domains.

So what is the solution here?

I am not sure that I can use service like no-ip.com as I am the client, not the server in this case.

Comment: I am not sure about the title. `How to have a static IP to log to a secured FTP?` reads to me as 'do I need a static IP to log in to sFTP`.

To which the anser is a simple no. You do not need it on behalf of the [s]FTP server.

Qua policies though, if the firm requires you to specify your IP and only allows connection from that specific IP then yes, you will either need a fixed IP somewhere, or a way to rapidly update the allowed IP.


Before we go into more details: Will you be using FTP or sFTP (FTP being old old old old, insecure and should go the way of dinosaurs).

Comment: @Hennes Changed the title. I need static IP which will be listed on the FTP server. Only whitelisted IPs can get access. I have dynamic IP that changes every day.

Comment: Can you speak with the service to see your options? They may have an option to help you out. Depends on their customer support. But most companies or small start ups that offer services like this will be able to help you accommodate.

Comment: Aye. That may be the best option. A possible but somewhat ugly workaround is to get a VPS or a dedicated server with a stable IP to FTP from. ( SecureSite --- VPS woth stable IP ---- Your desktop).  That would require tranfering things twice though, and you will have another system which needs to be kept up to date. Not recommended as a permanent solution, but possibly useful as a temorarily quick fix.

Comment: Hmm VPN may actually be a solution if I find the server with a static IP. Thanks. I will check that